# How to group pandas dataframe by date with overlapping sliding window?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For a Pandas dataframe with datetimes like:

```
DateTime
2020-6-12
2020-6-13
2020-6-14
2020-6-15
2020-6-16
2020-6-17
...
```

I want to group the series per 3 days and use a sliding window of 1 day. So the desired result is like:

```
Group
2020-6-12 2020-6-14
2020-6-13 2020-6-15
2020-6-14 2020-6-16
2020-6-15 2020-6-17
...
```

Grouping the data per 3 days could be achieved with:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='3D'))
```

However, the question is how to do this with a two days overlap? I prefer to see a solution with Pandas functions, otherwise a custom/workaround solution where the same `DataFrameGroupBy` type is kept intact is also fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution?